# How to get row name in crosstab query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I get row name in crosstab query?

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Cl7.png

I had click on first field in cross **APRIL** and **REGION1** (which value is **13**).
I need to know names of row (**APRIL**) and column (**REGION1**).

To get column name I use **Screen.ActiveControl.Name**, but I have no idea how to get row name

Answer (score 0):

Rows in tables for Access don't have name properties since they are merely values for differnt columns/fields) ordered next to one another.

You can query the crosstab query using the following SQL if you want to get the intersecting value in column "REGION1" in the row where "MONTH" = APRIL:

```
SELECT    REGION1 
FROM      TableName 
WHERE     Month = 'April'
```